# Reset the count using "keyset pagination"

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to use "keyset pagination", on this no problem, I do my query and save the last `id` found for the next one.
My doubt was how to reset the count, to return to `0`.
Currently, I am running an additional query every time to check if the `id` I saved is equal to the `SELECT MAX(id) FROM users` of the table and in that case update the saved `id` as `0`, otherwise update it keeping the correct count..
Is there a better way?

---

I was thinking something like (**it's a "pseudo-sql" just to show my idea**):

```sql
SELECT 0 OR MAX(id) FROM users_table WHERE (SELECT MAX(id) FROM users_table) =/!= :actual_count
```

---

### Update

#### Perhaps it is better to use an example:

Suppose I have 1000 entries in my table and I browse these 100 entries per request to an endpoint.

```sql
INSERT INTO util_table (`key`, `value`) VALUES ("last_visited_id", 0)
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE id >= (SELECT `value` FROM util_table WHERE `key` = "last_visited_id")
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 100
```

After this query, I update the value of the `last_visited_id` key in the util table.
So that the second time, I can continue counting from where I left off (100 to 200).

---

Now let's say I redo the query a tenth time so that I end up with rows from 900 to 1000.
The eleventh time and further, if I just kept saving the `id` value (1000..1100..1200..etc..), would give an empty result.
And with this back to my question, what is the best method to reset that key to 0?

Answer (score 1):

If you are, say, display 10 items per 'page', `SELECT` 11 each time.

Then observe how many rows were returned by the Select:

- <= 10 -- That's the 'last' page.
- 11    -- There are more page(s).  Show 10 on this page; fetch 10 for the next page (that will include re-fetching the 11th).

There is no need to fetch `MAX(id)`.

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination